# Werror doesn't make all warnings into errors

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

In general, the flag `-Werror` is to make all warnings into errors. But it is not always the same.

```
int j;

int main()
{
    int i = 10; 
    return 0;
}
```

If I type `g++ -Werror main.cpp`, there aren't any tips.
If I type `g++ -Wall main.cpp`, there is a warning:

> main.c: In function ‘main’: main.c:5:9: warning: unused variable ‘i’
>   [-Wunused-variable]

Can anyone explain it?

Moreover,

1. Why isn't there a warning about the variable `j`?
2. How can I remove "warnings being treated as errors"?

Thanks.

Comment: `j` is not warned because, being a global variable, it might be used in a different compilation unit via `extern`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-Werror` turns all warnings defined by other switches into errors, so you'll have to use `-Wall` as well as `-Werror`.

```
g++ -Werror -Wall main.cpp
```

Moreover, since `j` isn't marked `static`, there is no guarantee that it won't be used outside of the compilation unit it's defined in, so the compiler can't assume it's unused.